# Join and color TRs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have the following structure:

```
[{
  "ID": "1",
  "Country": "Italy",
  "Animals": {
    "dog": {
      "name|1": "Bailey",
      "age|1": "5",
      "name|2": "Charlie",
      "age|2": "3"
    },
    "cat": {
      "name|1": "Luna ",
      "age|1": "7",
      "name|2": "Biscuit",
      "age|2": "1"
    }
  }
}, {
  "ID": "4",
  "Country": "France",
  "Animals": {
    "cat": {
      "name|1": "Chloe",
      "age|1": "8",
      "name|2": "Jasper",
      "age|2": "2"
    },
    "mouse": {
      "name|1": "Skittles",
      "age|1": "6",
      "name|2": "Indy",
      "age|2": "9",
      "name|3": "Goldie",
      "age|3": "3"
    }
  }
}, {
  "ID": "6",
  "Country": "Spain",
  "Animals": {
    "cat": {
      "name|1": "Toby",
      "age|1": "7",
      "name|2": "Simba",
      "age|2": "2"
    }
  }
}, {
  "ID": "9",
  "Country": "Germany",
  "Animals": {
    "mouse": {
      "name": "Crimsin",
      "age": "1"
    }
  }
}]
```

I want to display it as the following table:

[image: desired table]

---

Some notes:

- The attributes of each animal (name, age) are identified by a pipe `|` followed by an id:

  - `name|1` and `age|1` are the attributes of the first animal (e.g. dog1)
  - `name|2` and `age|2` are the attributes of the second animal (e.g. dog2)
- When there is no pipe, as in the last example, there will be only 1 animal

---

This is my approach:

```
$.each(arr, function(key, value) {
  var rowspan = Object.keys(arr[key].Animals).length;

  var tr = "";
  c = 0;
  $.each(value, function(key2, value2) {
    if (key2 != "animals") {
      if (rowspan < 1) {
        rowspan = 1;
      }
      tr += '<td rowspan=' + rowspan + '>' + value2 + '</td>';
    } else {
      $.each(value2, function(key3, value3) {
        var tr2_temp = "";

        tr2_temp += "<td>" + key3 + "</td>";
        $.each(value3, function(key4, value4) {
          tr2_temp += "<td>" + value4 + "</td>";
        });

        if (c == 0) {
          $('#myTab tr:eq(' + parseInt(key + 1) + ')').append(tr2_temp)
          c++;
        } else {
          $('#myTab tr:eq(' + parseInt(key + 1) + ')').after(tr2_temp)
          c = 0;
        }
      });
    }
  });
  console.log(tr)
  $('#myTab > tbody:last-child').append('<tr>' + tr + '</tr>');
});
```

But it doesn't help.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwwp9b24/).

Comment: Would be easier using nested arrays instead of objects...do you control the structure of the data source?

Comment: that structure is awful. Why would anyone use delimiters inside the property name to denote a new record, when you can just use arrays of objects instead as already suggested. If it's not your data source, have a strong word with whoever created it :-)

Comment: @charlietfl: Yes, I do.

Comment: @ADyson: The names come directly from the database column names. We need them for other things as well, so it would take a really long time changing the entire structure.

Comment: it should be very simple to change the structure of Animals to arrays of objects with consistent property names. Probably much easier than what you are doing now in your back end

Comment: I don't believe that your column names are "name|1", "name|2", "name|3"...etc. Because it would have to go to infinity and add a new column every time you add a new record.

Comment: a sensible structure might look like this: `{
  "ID": "1",
  "Country": "Italy",
  "Animals": {
 "dogs" :
 [
  { name: "Bailey", "age":5},
  { name: "Charlie", "age":3}
 ],
 "cats" :
 [
  { name: "Luna", "age":7},
  { name: "Bicuit", "age":1}
 ]
  }
}
`

Comment: or this: `{
  "ID": "1",
  "Country": "Italy",
  "Animals": [
  { species: "dog", name: "Bailey", "age":5},
  { species: "dog", name: "Charlie", "age":3}
  { species: "cat", name: "Luna", "age":7},
  { species: "cat", name: "Bicuit", "age":1}
  ]
}` Maybe you would have an extra property in each individual animal object for its unique ID as well, if needed.

Comment: @ADyson: Unfortunately, this is the truth. Please note, that this is not a "real world" example. In the real case there are much more columns (i.e. attributes) and every component can consist of a maximum of 3 entries (i.e. max 3 dogs, max 3 cats, etc.).

Comment: ok. fair enough. but the real fix is to normalise the database. It will just continue to create annoying problems like this one until it's sorted out. I realise that may be a lot of work, but if you plan to build a lot more things on top of this data then it's almost certainly worth the effort.

Comment: @ADyson: Ok, I've updated my data structure.

Comment: it's an improvement, but doing it as per my second example would make the resulting code to build the table more straightforward. You're still using individual properties within the "animals" object to enumerate the list, when this is exactly what the purpose of an array is - to hold a list of similar objects which is simple to loop through. You're also holding the animal's ID as the name of the object, not as a value (another symptom of what I've just described, by not using arrays). ID should be one of the properties of the animal object...

Comment: ...As it is now, you would have to read the actual name of the property in order to create the "dog1" string, rather than reading the _values_, which is how data structures are meant to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data set is crazy :D but here is your answer:

```js
const data = [{ "ID": "1", "Country": "Italy", "Animals": { "dog": { "name|1": "Bailey", "age|1": "5", "name|2": "Charlie", "age|2": "3" }, "cat": { "name|1": "Luna ", "age|1": "7", "name|2": "Biscuit", "age|2": "1" } } }, { "ID": "4", "Country": "France", "Animals": { "cat": { "name|1": "Chloe", "age|1": "8", "name|2": "Jasper", "age|2": "2" }, "mouse": { "name|1": "Skittles", "age|1": "6", "name|2": "Indy", "age|2": "9", "name|3": "Goldie", "age|3": "3" } } }, { "ID": "6", "Country": "Spain", "Animals": { "cat": { "name|1": "Toby", "age|1": "7", "name|2": "Simba", "age|2": "2" } } }, { "ID": "9", "Country": "Germany", "Animals": { "mouse": { "name": "Crimsin", "age": "1" } } }]

const createTable = (data) => {
  data = data.sort((x, y) => x.ID - y.ID)
  data.forEach(x => {
    const obj = {}
    for (let animalType in x.Animals) {
      obj[animalType] = []
      const animaliInfo = x.Animals[animalType]
      const animaliInfoKeys = Object.keys(x.Animals[animalType])
      for (let i = 0; i < animaliInfoKeys.length; i += 2) {
        obj[animalType].push({
          name: animaliInfo[animaliInfoKeys[i]],
          age: animaliInfo[animaliInfoKeys[i + 1]],
          number: (animaliInfoKeys[i].match(/\d+/) || [])[0] || ""
        })
      }
    }
    x.Animals = obj
    return x
  })

  const table = document.createElement('table')
  {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    ['ID', 'Country', 'Animals','Name','Age'].forEach(x => {
      const td = document.createElement('td')
      td.innerText = x
      tr.appendChild(td)
    })
    table.append(tr)
    }
  for (const x of data) {
    let rowspam = 0
    let firstTr
    for (const animals in x.Animals) {
      for (const animal of x.Animals[animals]) {
        const tr = document.createElement('tr')
        if (!firstTr) {
          firstTr = tr
        }
        const typeAndNumber = document.createElement('td')
        typeAndNumber.innerText = animals + animal.number
        const name = document.createElement('td')
        name.innerText = animal.name
        const age = document.createElement('td')
        age.innerText = animal.age

        tr.appendChild(typeAndNumber)
        tr.appendChild(name)
        tr.appendChild(age)
        table.appendChild(tr)
        rowspam++
      }
    }
    const ID = document.createElement('td')
    const country = document.createElement('td')

    const firstTd = firstTr.children[0]
    ID.innerText = x.ID
    country.innerText = x.Country
    ID.rowSpan = rowspam
    country.rowSpan = rowspam
    firstTr.insertBefore(ID, firstTd)
    firstTr.insertBefore(country, firstTd)
  }
  return table
}
const table = createTable(data)
table.border = "1"
document.body.appendChild(table)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

### How it works:

**setp 1** sorting by ID.
**step 2** changing Alminals Objects to Array of objects.
**step 3** create DOM elements.

Comment: Fixed heading .

Comment: Thank you, that works great, but only in this simplified example. In the real case, there are much more columns. Is there any way to make it more dynamic, so that I don't have to specify every one of them: `tr.appendChild(typeAndNumber)
        tr.appendChild(name)
        tr.appendChild(age)`?

Comment: You would have to change data structure because it doesnt make sence :/

Comment: @user1170330 could animals be writen as array ? i mean `Animals->cat|dog...->[]`

Comment: I can control the data structure, it is built with PHP. So: yes, just edit it as you like, I can then adjust it later.

Comment: Actualy I dont have enough time today :/ it must be solved using recursion if you want it to work in all cases [here](https://gist.github.com/koziejka/ccf8f02daba6a53c4c7e87f13d214393) if data set i sugest.